# How one process can wait for input from another in PHP?

Tags: php, input, process, wait

I'm using **proc_open** to run another process and after that in while loop I wan't to send some data (using pipes) to opened process and recieve it output. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) to create or connect to a socket and then select on the socket. or [Semaphore][1]
[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php
functions